# game manager script for hierarchy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue I'd appreciate help with. I'm trying to create game manager script that simply dictates if I have 5 objective game objects, the player is only allowed to complete them from the smallest (the smallest available objective will be indicated by the game manager) and it becomes a foul if he attempts the 2nd objective if the first is still there.

```
public class gameobjects : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    int ballsLeft = 0;
    bool PocketedAllBalls = false;
    void Start () {
        ballsLeft = 10; // or more;

    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    GameObject[] balls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("balls");
        ballsLeft = balls.Length;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            ballsLeft --;
        }
        if(ballsLeft == 0)
        {
            endGame();
        }
    }
    
    void endGame()
    {
        PocketedAllBalls = true;
    }
    
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(PocketedAllBalls)
        {
        GUI.Label(new Rect (0,0,200,20),"all gone");
        }
        else
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect (0,0,200,20),"Balls Remaining : " + ballsLeft);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question.

Comment: I am new to both C# and game making However I'm developing a taste for it …. I have a task that i have no clue how to achieve, the task is on how to script a game manager that shows the player which object to move first in a field with five or more objects

Comment: >  which object to move first in a field with five or more objects <
In what order should they be in? What condition are you checking for? So you have 5 balls and a player. Do you want to show which ball is the nearest to the player?

Comment: from the smallest to the largest just like in 9 ball

Comment: Does this mean I might not get Aid from all this great minds?

Comment: I would help you if you would formulate a clear question on what you are trying to do.
>from the smallest to the largest just like in 9 ball< Do you mean a value inside a script? Do you want to order by `transform.size`? I have no idea _where_, _how_ and _by what_ value you want to order the objects.

Comment: I have 5 balls (numbers 1 to 5) instead of targeting balls nearest to the player I'd like to target them according to the number of the ball, starting with ball 1.